# Error: validation failed: [serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress" not found, serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress-backend" not found,

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

getting this error from today evening in google cloud . Something happened wrong with gcloud. Same commands were working till yesterday.

```
helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

i have followed steps:
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4K3A.png)

```
(mykubeproject1)$ helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --set controller.publishService.enabled=true
```

Error: validation failed: [serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress" not found, serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress-backend" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingres
s" not found, clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, rolebindings.rbac.authoriza
tion.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, services "nginx-ingress-controller" not found, services "nginx-ingress-default-backend" not found, deployments.apps "nginx-ingress-con
troller" not found, deployments.apps "nginx-ingress-default-backend" not found]

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes are you using with GKE? Was your `tiller-deploy` deployment ready `1/1` when you invoked command `helm install ...`? What is your helm and tiller version?

Answer (score 1):

It is an issue with Helm 2.16.4: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7797

Upgrade Helm 2.16.5 will fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: downgrade helm and tiller versions. I downgraded all the way to 2.14.3 but that was probably not necessary; I just happened to know that version would work for me.

Below are versions etc of a system exhibiting the same behaviour as in the question:

helm version:

```sh
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.4", GitCommit:"5e135cc465d4231d9bfe2c5a43fd2978ef527e83", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.4", GitCommit:"5e135cc465d4231d9bfe2c5a43fd2978ef527e83", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

kubectl version:

```sh
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.3", GitCommit:"06ad960bfd03b39c8310aaf92d1e7c12ce618213", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-11T18:14:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.10-gke.24", GitCommit:"f2734800eba37df4400813ab9340886059d56105", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-05T18:38:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12b4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

tiller-deploy is running (1/1).

Installing any helm chart, locally or from stable, results in the error posted above.

The output above is from a gke cluster, but I got the same behaviour locally on minikube.