# Ingress-Controller Deployment is failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy ingress-controller in GKE - K8S cluster where RBAC is enabled, but I am getting below error.

[image: W]

This is the command I ran ...

helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --set controller.publishService.enabled=true

it gave me below error
                                                                                                            Error: validation failed: [serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress" not found, serviceaccounts "nginx-ingress-backend" not found, clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, roles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "nginx-ingress" not found, services "nginx-ingress-controller" not found, services "nginx-ingress-default-backend" not found, deployments.apps "nginx-ingress-controller" not found, deployments.apps "nginx-ingress-default-backend" not found]

I am following this link : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

Could you please share your thoughts to debug this issue and also to fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't see anything..add logs not images

Comment: This is the command I ran ...helm install --name nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true --set controller.publishService.enabled=true it gave me below error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue in Helm 2.16.4: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7797

You can upgrade Helm to 2.16.5 to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you , sure I will try.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple workaround: **downgrade helm and tiller versions**.

Here are the steps how to do it: [downgrade-helm-tiller](https://medium.com/@jyotirbhandari/how-to-downgrade-helm-version-on-server-and-client-4838ca100dbf).

Remember that helm version on the server and client should be same to communicate.

Similar problems: [helm-validation-failed](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7797),  [validation-helm-install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60836127/error-validation-failed-serviceaccounts-nginx-ingress-not-found-serviceacc/60846646#60846646).

Useful documentation: [gke-nginx-ingress](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke).

Comment: Thank you , sure I will try.